# full name of each variable in Plotmo graph

Tags: machine-learning, r

R function plotmo http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/gallery/plotmo.html is used for plotting dependence plot from e.g. decision tree model.

In some cases, resulting graph does not print full names of features on each plot. What I am saying is, e.g. the "feature1" is automatically renamed "f1" or something similar.

I want full name. But plotmo just adjust automatically to short name (I believe for memory convenience, but not useful for perception).

Maybe Plotmo has parameter forcing it to produce full name? I just see -main parameter. But what values to set as to produce full original feature names for each generated plot?

Comment: Hi, Do you have a small example of input to recreate the problem? What version of plotmo package are you using?